# How to collapse navigation menu when screen gets smaller?

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to do this

https://i.gyazo.com/96c914cfce7e996a36471a4b3633d7b9.mp4

When screen gets to width of 500 or less a menu appears that can be toggled like above.

I'm struggling in making the menu collapsible. This is what I did.

https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-dawn-hy2ohf?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  MenuItem,
  MenuList,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  IconButton
} from "@mui/material";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";

export default function App() {
  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          "@media screen and (max-width: 500px)": {
            justifyContent: "space-between"
          }
        }}
      >
        <IconButton>
          <HomeIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <MenuList
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            "@media screen and (max-width: 500px)": {
              display: !toggleMenu ? "none" : "flex"
            }
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem>Category one</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Category two</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>

        <IconButton
          onClick={() => setToggleMenu(!toggleMenu)}
          sx={{
            display: "none",
            "@media screen and (max-width: 500px)": {
              display: "block"
            }
          }}
        >
          {!toggleMenu ? <MenuIcon /> : <CloseIcon />}
        </IconButton>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

I'm unsure how to make this vertically aligned like in the video above.

Answer (score -1):

- The `@media` tags are actually css. You should make a second `.css` file and import it in the `.js` file using `import 'yourfile.css`.
- Then you can use the `className` tag on your react JSX elements to add the styles

In your `.js` file:

```
<Toolbar className='toolbar'>
  ...
</Toolbar>
```

For example: in your `.css` file:

```
toolbar: {
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
    "@media screen and (max-width: 500px)": {
      justifyContent: "space-between"
    }
}
```

If you use sass and have a `.scss` file, you can surround classes with @media and it works really nicely:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  yourClass: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference? (also, this doesn't answer the question)